# gulp breaks when dynamically generating key for javascript objects.

Tags: javascript, gulp

when I am creating dynamic keys of javascript objects, it breaks gulp minification process.

```
var a = "custome_name"
var b = {[a]:"myName"}
// {custome_name: "myName"} - works fine but breaks in gulp minification task.
```

what other syntax I can use for that?

Comment: I think the problem is that the dynamic key is ES6 syntax. The Gulp minified (presumably Uglify2) can only compress ES5 code. You'll have to transpile the code before minifying, e.g. using Babel

Comment: what is the ES5 syntax I can use to create dynamic key for js objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a variable (`a`) as a property name inside an object literal.

While this is valid for ES6, it is not for ES5 syntax. The Gulp minifier you are using (presumably [Uglify2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)) does not support minification of ES6 syntax.

If you don't want to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to convert your code from ES6 to ES5, you can rewrite your code to work around the issue like this:

```
var a = "custome_name"
var b = {}
b[a] = "myName"
```

Instead of creating the object with the dynamic key directly, create an empty object first, which you can then assign the value to using the dynamic key and brackets.

→ See related question: [Using a Variable for a Key in a JavaScript Object Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)